# How to Restart Countdown Timer After Every 90 Hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var days = 03; var hours = 18; var minutes = 00; var seconds = 00;
    function calculate()
    {
setTimeout(calculate, 1000); $('#showDate').html(days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
        seconds--;
        if (seconds < 0) { seconds = 59; minutes--;
        if (minutes < 0) { hours--; minutes = 59;
        if (hours   < 0) { days--; hours = 23;
        if (days    < 0) {  days = 0; hours = 0; minutes = 0; seconds = 0;
        }}}}
    }
    calculate();
});
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<div id='showDate'></div>
```

Hope so you all will be fine.

Come to the Point, I want to reset the count down that i created using jquery after every 90 hours.

I had written below code yet.

It does not reset after 90 hours means after 3 days and 18 hours.

Kindly Help me.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var days = 03; var hours = 18; var minutes = 00; var seconds = 00;
    function calculate()
    {
setTimeout(calculate, 1000); $('#showDate').html(days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
        seconds--;
        if (seconds < 0) { seconds = 59; minutes--;
        if (minutes < 0) { hours--; minutes = 59;
        if (hours   < 0) { days--; hours = 23;
        if (days    < 0) {  days = 0; hours = 0; minutes = 0; seconds = 0;
        }}}}
    }
    calculate();
});
</script>

<div id='showDate'></div>
```

Comment: set "==" in if condition that should do it.

Comment: rewrite the code kindly if u can :)

Comment: Better approach would be to set start timestamp in some variable and calc passage from that

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like following :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var days = 00; var hours = 00; var minutes = 1; var seconds = 00;
        function calculate()
        {
    setTimeout(calculate, 1000); $('#showDate').html(days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
        if(days == 0 && hours ==00 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 00)
        {
            minutes = 1;
        }
            seconds--;
            if (seconds < 0) { seconds = 59; minutes--;
            if (minutes < 0) { hours--; minutes = 59;
            if (hours   < 0) { days--; hours = 23;
            if (days    < 0) {  days = 0; hours = 0; minutes = 0; seconds = 0;
            }}}}
        }
        calculate();
    });
    </script>

    <div id='showDate'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var days = 03; var hours = 18; var minutes = 00; var seconds = 00;
    function calculate()
    {
setTimeout(calculate, 1000); $('#showDate').html(days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
        seconds--;
        if (seconds < 0) { seconds = 59; minutes--;
        if (minutes < 0) { hours--; minutes = 59;
        if (hours   < 0) { days--; hours = 23;
        if (days    < 0) {  days = 0; hours = 0; minutes = 0; seconds = 0;
        }}}}
        if((seconds == 0) && (minutes == 0) && (hours == 0) && (days == 0))
        {
            days = 03;
            hours = 18;
            minutes = 00;
            seconds = 20;
        }
    }
    calculate();
});
</script>

<div id='showDate'></div>
```